# Printing verbatim command inputs in commands

Tags: macros, verbatim

I want to define a command `\mydef` that does something like this:

```
\mydef{\foo{bar}}
```

produces

```
\def\foo{bar} \verb|\foo=bar|
```

The command:

```
\newcommand{\mydef}[1]{\def #1}
```

does the first bit, but I don't seem to be able to use verbatim in a command - how do I access the contents of `#1`? In this context I would be happy if I could just discard the first character...

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: Could you explain the "In this context I would be happy if I could just discard the first character..." a little but more. The ``\`` of `\foo`, or the `b` of `bar`?

Comment: Does `bar` really be read verbatim or do you only want to display it so, but keep it normal for the definition of `\foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\string` to print the command as string and `\strip@prefix` in combination with `\meaning` to display the macro content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mydef}[2]{%
    \def#1{#2}%
    {\ttfamily\string#1=\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mydef\foo{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @chl: Thanks. The `\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning` is actually taken from `\@onelevel@sanitize`.